# Jar file from desktop libgdx project in netbeans

Tags: java, libgdx, executable-jar

How can I get a jar file from a desktop libgdx project in netbeans?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late and you've probably figured it out by now, but I'll still answer this for those who don't know.

1. Right click on your desktop project
2. Go to the "Tasks" menu
3. Click "dist"

This will create a standalone JAR file in `<pathToYourProject>\desktop\build\libs` called `desktop-1.0.jar` (or something like that).

I don't know if that's the proper way to do it, but it's the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with this but you should be able to [unpack/extract the jar file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/unpack.html) and then load then load the project into Netbeans.

- [If it's a gradle project.](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-NetBeans)
- If it's not search further since I do not know Netbeans.
- Import it with Android Studio and work with my favorite IDE. Choose *import none android studio project*.